# How to capture a string in a certain position inside another string in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to replace hundreds of thousands of sql lines like this one:

UPDATE table1 SET id = 2651,label = 'Black' WHERE `table`.`id` = 2651;

How can I capture the word inside the single quotes (in this case is 'Black')?

Comment: I've used the combination of fopen(), fgets(), str_replace() and file_put_contents(). The result was good except there many redundancies (same line were added multiple lines). I think it's better to capture the word inside the quotes then check it against the new word arrays. But I don't know how to capture that word in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with that request as a string, here's what you could do using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :
`$req = "UPDATE table1 SET id = 2651,label = 'Black' WHERE table.id = 2651;"`

- To capture the word 'Black' in `$req` :
  `$pat = '/label = \'(.*?)\'/';
  preg_match($pat, $req, $matches);
  echo $matches[1];`
- To replace the word 'Black' in `$req` (the above step is not necessary) :
  `$newReq = preg_replace('/label = \'(.*?)\'/', 'label = \'white\'', $req);
  echo $newReq;`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions - look at the documentation for `preg_replace`. To match `label = 'Black'` you can use a regex along the lines of: `label\s*=\s*\'Black\'`

Comment: Thanks. Since the word inside the quotes can be anything, can I just use **label\s*=\s*\'*\'** in preg_match() or preg_replace()? I'm quite confused with regex.

Comment: Dot (.) matches any character and star ( * ) means zero or more, so .* translates to "any character any number of times". label\s*=\s*\'.*\' is what you need

Comment: Unfortunately, I got alphanumeric or backlash delimiter error.